# Is there a way to change the password_reset_confirm link sent by django?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using the django inbuilt authentication. When a password reset email is sent to the user it contains a link. I want to be able to simply change that link to something else. Because I have a front-end angularJS application. So, I want the link in the email to be something my AngularApp can intercept.

This is the template that sends the email https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html#L6

I simply want to change `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` to `http://localhost:8001/passwordResetConfirm/uid/token`

Comment: If you create an `registration/password_reset_email.html` template in your templates directory, then you can change the link to anything you want. However, if you don't include the token in the url, I don't see how it can be much use to reset the password.

Answer (score 1):

Just redefine the url with the name `'password_reset_confirm'` **after** the inclusion of `django.contrib.auth.urls`.  If there is several urls with the same name then the URL dispatcher uses the last occurrence:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^passwordResetConfirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})$',
                              auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                              name='password_reset_confirm'),
)
```